# Possible to create parallax effect without background-image on a div?

Tags: html, css, parallax

I know how to create a parallax effect using background-size on a div and using background-attachment etc, but if I have code (created by a Wordpress plugin) that looks something like this:

```
<div class="big-leader>
<div class="backstretch">
<img src="background-image.jpg">
</div>
</div>
```

how do I create a parallax effect on that? Is it possible without applying background-image on a div (with css?)

Comment: What are you parallax scrolling if there is no image?

Comment: The background-image is not in a div. It's in a img-tag.I want the background-image.jpg be that image (that is otherwise set in a background-image style)

Comment: Are you thinking of a parallax background or a fixed attachment background?

Comment: Even though I don't use to have W3Schools as a ref I just explain what I want :-) http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp

Comment: In most of the parallax plugins you noticed that it is the `background-position` that changes, if their would be anyway to do it in `top` for div or image, it will be possible...

Answer (score 1):

i think you can simply get the image source and apply it to the parent div's background image and then remove the image. something like this :

**sample CSS :**

```
.backstretch {
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 200px auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="big-leader">
    <div class="backstretch">
        <img src="test.png">
    </div>
    <div class="backstretch">
        <img src="test1.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY :**

```
$(function() {
    $('.backstretch').each(function(index, el) {
        var img = $(el).children('img');
        $(el).css('background', 'url(' + img.attr('src') + ') 50% 50% / cover fixed');
        img.remove();
    });
});
```

```js
$(function() {
   $('.backstretch').each(function(index, el) {
    var img = $(el).children('img');
    $(el).css('background', 'url(' + img.attr('src') + ') 50% 50% / cover fixed');
    img.remove();
   });
  });
```

```css
.backstretch {
   width: 50%;
   height: 200px;
   margin: 200px auto;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="big-leader">
  <div class="backstretch">
   <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="backstretch">
   <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x200">
  </div>
 </div>
```